# Do colleges have students that writing coach for free for practice?

Tags: education

I have already worked with a university program to get a student life coach to work with me for free for practice, with good results.  I am wondering if there are similar opportunities to get writing coaching for free.  I have thought of contact MFA programs at colleges, but that is sort of an intensive process, so I wanted to ask this forum first.

Comment: At the University of Saskatchewan, there was a writing help centre. That maybe what you are looking for??? Not sure --- also what country are you in that may help you get more targeted answers.

Comment: Are you a college student looking to get help with writing homework?  If so, your college will have resources.  Or are you a member of the public asking for free writing help?  That's a bit harder.  You might want to ask the local junior colleges about writing classes (if you're in the US; elsewhere they may have different names, but they're for 2-year degrees or just extra training, and they're generally inexpensive).  They and other schools will have classes for the public that don't require you to be a regular student.

Comment: I certainly hope not! Writers get paid little enough as it is.

Answer (score 1):

This strongly depends on the college you attend. My university had a free Writing Center with staff that you could make an appointment with. There were also student and school-sponsored tutoring resources that offered help with writing.

To find these, you can check your course webpages and ask your classmates. Professors will sometimes direct students to relevant resources in the class syllabus. If you can, take a writing elective.

The resources you look for also depend on what you want to improve, be it technical writing, communicate professionally via email, or write journal-worthy poetry. If you have declared your major or program, check with your adviser for field-specific resources. If you're undeclared, try checking with your school's career or tutoring centers, if they exist. A school or local library would also be a good place to ask for resources.

There are also plenty of online resources that introduce you to various citation systems and the writing process, the first coming to mind is the [Purdue Owl](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/index.html)

Comment: Hi Verona, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. This is a great first answer! Thanks for participating and happy writing!